# Im trying to complete my HTML/CSS assessment. But Im not sure if my HMTL and CSS code is done correctly. My pics won't show

Tags: html, css

Im trying to complete my HTML/CSS asessment. But I'm not sure if my HMTL and CSS code is done correctly. My pics won't show up. I don't know what to do. Looking for some guidance. Attached is my HTML code and my CSS code.

[image: Screenshot of CSS] •
[image: Screenshot of HTML]

I've refreshed the page a few times and reread the lectures but I do not what to do, and I'm extremely new to the craft of programming

Comment: Pics? There are no references to any pictures in the code. Can you try describing it better? I don't think I understand the issue. Also please don't use screenshots to show code. Just send code directly.

Comment: sorry I didn't send the entire code. I have now been able to get my pictures to show up but i think they are too big. Here is the HTML code..I can show you the CSS if the html looks fine to you. thanks

Comment: How can I send the code directly?

Comment: We don't debug images

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks. As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, assuming you make sure to include an image in the same folder as the html file.

```
 <img src="yourPicture.jpg" alt="A very shot description of your picture">
```

Further explanation:
To include images in HTML files, we use the `<imag>` tag. The image tag must have a valid `src` attribute, as it is telling the browser to where to look for the image.

The `alt` attribute is not mandatory but very useful for making accessible HTMLs. [You can learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Answer (score -1):

You need an `img` tag in your HTML file:

```html
<img src="path of your img">
```

(Or you can add an `img` in your CSS file .)

Comment: thanks.. i added it. Can you take a look at it?